# Broad flight search with specific stopover

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

**Are there websites that allow for a broad search that passes via specific connection airports?**

In the case of a one-way flight, I would like to find which flights depart from a certain city (A) and go to anywhere while stopping at city (B). For two-way flights, the return should go back from C to A, where C is what was the selected *anywhere* destination, possibly with a stopover at a fourth city D.

In other words I want the final destination to be unspecified but to specify the intermediate stops to take advantage of stopovers. This has to be a reasonable route for someone going from A to C, not just a random flight from B onward.

EDIT: I do not want a single use answer but a way to learn how to do this. With my frequent flyer points program, I often have options to include stop-over for no cost. Most times I search for the destination and choose one on the way to back as stop over but often there are no more stop-overs that I have no visited or the destination is too close. Moreover, when redeeming points, the region is offered as a single cost, so it's better if I found a further destination and use my indented location as a stopover.

Comment: You may want to clarify if you want just a stop/layover (usually a few hours, with your luggage checked through) or a stopover (staying one or more nights)

Comment: Actually I do want a stopover but I don't mind if the search yields a layover if I can expanded it to a stopover for a fee later. It would be extremely complex for a flight search to also yield various lengths of stopovers.

Comment: Most of the cheapest fares don’t allow stopovers, you often have to upgrade to substantially more expensive fares to be able to switch to a stopover.

Comment: Name your cities or this needs to be closed as too broad. The answer will vastly differ if you are within Europe, within USA or intercontinental flights are involved and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a lot like hidden-city ticketing, which carries some serious risks. Here are [some instructions](https://airfarespot.com/2015/11/23/hidden-city-airfare-search/) if you're determined to do this. On [matrix.itasoftware.com](http://matrix.itasoftware.com) you still have to put the destination city C, but it can be a long list of possible airport codes. You can put in airport code B as "routing code" under "Advanced controls".

Comment: It's similar, except that I intend to go to the final destination too. Only I have in mind a destination that I really like which is close but I would like to enjoy seeing another further place. Going multi-city is usually very pricey but if you find a route with a stop, you can often change it into a stop-over (depending the airline for a modest fee).

Comment: You can add `minconn` advanced control to have a really long layover in matrix as well.